# Set ImageView height of ListView Header

Tags: android, listview, header, imageview

I'm currently trying to set the height of an `ImageView`, placed as `ListView` header, but i'm always getting an `NullPointerExpection` in `imageHeaderView.getLayoutParams`. Here's my code:

```
ImageView imageHeaderView = new ImageView(this);
imageHeaderView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
R.drawable.deckblatt));

imageHeaderView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
imageHeaderView.getLayoutParams().height = 50;  
myList.addHeaderView(imageHeaderView);
```

Is it not possible to get/set the `layoutParams`, when used in a `ListView` header?
What else can i do to set the height of my `ImageView`?

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this--->

```
ImageView imageHeaderView = new ImageView(this);
imageHeaderView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.deckblatt));
imageHeaderView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
imageHeaderView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(100, 100));  
myList.addHeaderView(imageHeaderView);
```

Comment: instead of `imageHeaderView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.deckblatt));` use  `imageHeaderView.setImageResource(R.drawable.deckblatt);`

Comment: Thank's for your help, but although it keeps crashing. The new problem is a ClassCastException.. from ViewGroup$LayoutParams to AbsListView$LayoutParams.

Comment: I fixed it by using 
  AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(100, 100); Maybe you can update your answer, so that i can mark it ase the correct one.